# How do I take in a matrix formatted like this as input in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, input

I understand there are similar questions, but none had an answer for this specific type of formatting. For a codeforces problem I need to take matrix input as such:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

and I want to store it as a matrix where m[i][j] is exactly the same as the input above. For example, I want to store the input as a matrix where [4][1] would correlate to 1. How do I take this input in python3? In case it is helpful, I have attached the problem here: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/263/A. The only other thing of note is that the matrix is always 5x5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use:**

```
N = 5 # Shape of the square matrix(NxN)
matrix = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(N)]

print(matrix)
print("Element at 2 row and 5 column is:", matrix[1][4])
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

Element at 2 row and 5 column is: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It'd be a lot more intuitive if you swap your [4][1], and denote matrix[1][4] = 1. In that case you can just store the matrix as a nested list, where each sub-list is a row. matrix[1][4] would trace back to element at row index 1 and column index 4